# Why the loop cannot work in this django views.py

Tags: python, django, view

I try to write a login page that will lock the user by inputting the wrong password three times and the username will go to the blacklist so that it will be locked. The login page works well and the blacklist works well.
One problem is the loop does not work, I had `while count < 3` in the beginning, but it only gives the user one chance to input password, then I rewrite the code as 'if elif' format to check what goes wrong. What I find is it stuck on "1 Username or Password is incorrect 1" which means it only goes to the first if and the count always is 1 which means the count goes back 0 every time.

I think that because after the user clicks the login button, the page refresh and makes the count 0 again, so how should I solve it?

```
@unauthenticated_user
def loginPage(request):

    if request.method == "POST":
        username = request.POST.get('username')  # Get username input first
        password = request.POST.get('password')
        user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
        BL = BlackList.objects.values_list('list', flat=True)  # Read all data into array
        if username in BL:  # Check if the username is in blacklist
            messages.info(request, 'Username in black list, please contact admin')
        else:  # Not in black list username can go to login
            count = 0
            if count == 0:  # User can try 3 times for each login in
                if user is not None:
                    login(request, user)
                    return redirect('home')
                else:
                    count = count+1
                    messages.info(request, '1 Username or Password is incorrect' + str(count))

            elif count == 1:
                messages.info(request, 'testest' + str(count))
                request.method == "POST"
                username = request.POST.get('username')  # Get username input first
                password = request.POST.get('password')
                user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
                if user is not None:
                    login(request, user)
                    return redirect('home')
                else:
                    count = count+1
                    messages.info(request, '2 Username or Password is incorrect' + str(count))
            elif count == 2:
                request.method == "POST"
                username = request.POST.get('username')  # Get username input first
                password = request.POST.get('password')
                user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
                if user is not None:
                    login(request, user)
                    return redirect('home')
                else:
                    count = count+1
                    messages.info(request, '3 Username or Password is incorrect' + str(count))

            else:  # 3 times fail the username will go to the black list
                BlackList.objects.create(list=username)
                # how to put the username in to BlackList?
                messages.info(request, 'Username in black list, please contact admin')

    context = {}
    return render(request, 'accounts/login.html', context)
```

Comment: This functionality must be implemented in the front end.

Comment: What you could do is create a separate model that stores IP address and the amount of login tries. Everytime it fails, you up the count for that IP address. Before the login method you check if that count value <= 3

Answer (score 0):

So when you're writing

```
else:
     count = count+1
     messages.info(request, '1 Username or Password is incorrect' + str(count))
```

you should do count += 1. So it should look like this

```
else:
     count += 1
     messages.info(request, '1 Username or Password is incorrect' + str(count))
```

do this for every place you put count = count + 1. The proper way is to do count += 1